# How to get updated datetime from updated records in sql server TSQL sp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have one main table `tbl_con` and one more Audit `tbl_Aud_con`. `tbl_con` has trigger(AFTER) when it gets updated.previous record(deleted) record will get inserted into the AUDIT table.

eg.

tbl_con

```
ID updated_date Fname Lname status 
1001 10-02-2017 ajay chain blocked
```

tbl_Aud_con

```
ID updated_date Fname Lname status 
1001 10-01-2017 ajay chain Allow
```

In this example Allowed record gets updated to blocked in main `tbl_con`.
I want that date when the record get updated. In this case its `10-02-2017` from `tbl_con`.

There are multiple cases. I want blocked record updated date only

1. when record is in main table and it is already blocked then its updated get will be shows.
2. Record is in main table in blocked status and its `NULL` status in audit then also main con tables updated date will be show.because this record is `NULL` first and its updated to blocked.
3. when records get multiple time allowed and blocked and its current status is blocked in main table.Then when its last changed to blocked will be shown. its difficult one because when other fields gets updated then also it has audit entries.

eg

tbl_con

```
ID updated_date Fname Lname status 
1001 10-05-2017 ajay chain blocked
```

tbl_Aud_con

```
ID updated_date Fname Lname status 
1001 10-01-2017 ajay chavan NULL
1001 10-02-2017 ajay chain Allow
1001 10-03-2017 ajay raj Blocked
1001 10-04-2017 ajay raj Allow
1001 10-05-2017 ajay chain blocked
1001 10-05-2017 ajay rock blocked
```

in this case record blocked at `10-04-2017` when the status is changed allow to blocked.

please help.